# Creating a Clipping Mask using Graphics32

Tags: delphi, graphics32

I'm using [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org) for image processing. Looking at its capabilities, it strikes me that I've yet to see a proper implementation of a clipping mask. I do see the term "clipping" pop up here and there, but it seems to refer to something else.

Simply put, I need one layer to function as a "peeking hole" to another; layer A should be projected onto layer B, but only where layer B is visible. (I see no further need to redefine what a clipping mask is.)

If it were just the bitmap of that other layer that I'd like to present, it wouldn't be so hard to do - then I could use [this trick](http://graphics32.org/news/newsgroups.php?art_group=graphics32.general&article_id=7179) - but what complicates things, is that the bitmap of a layer does not tell much about what would be displayed by the layer; the layer can be:

- (partially) invisible (when out of the view)
- moved/stretched + optionally resampled
- rotated

with no effects on its bitmap.

Is it actually so that there is no ready implementation for this? Any suggestions for doing this myself?

## Progress

I found some useful elements in the source of Graphics32. For example, using this declaration:

```
type
  TLayerAccess = class(TBitmapLayer);
```

to gain access to protected methods, I can call `TLayerAccess(ABitmapLayer).Paint(ABitmap32)` to have just this layer painted to a bitmap, exactly as it would to the screen.

Comment: graphics32 uses 32nit bitmaps solely and it's the alpha channel of the bitmap that is used for blending. I do not know of another alpha field you can use (eg clipping area etc). You only have another "master alpha". I would. 1. determine alpha bitmap (all white, alpha channel is the clipping path in bitmap coordinates), multiply original bitmap into this one and then render bitmap into destination.

Comment: How do you define what portions of layer B are visible ?

Comment: @iamjoosy By where I can see it when it is drawn to the container (TImage32).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TByteMap](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Units/GR32_OrdinalMaps/Classes/TByteMap/Methods/WriteTo.htm) and its writeTo method.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this myself a year ago, and quickly resorted to using a black layer with transparent parts. It suited my then needs. But what you want is possible..

You want to couple one TBitmapLayer to another and consider it its mask. I want to avoid these references however (and its potential problems and Graphics32 rework) and see this only as a last resort.

There is a way to do without a dedicated TBitmapLayer, using your own pixel combiner. But it doesn't know about TBitmapLayers and its XY pixels.

To proper occlude (or leave out) parts of a `TBitmapLayer` while drawing  to screen, you could  use create a method of [type `TPixelCombineEvent`](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Units/GR32/Types/TPixelCombineEvent.htm) and assigning this as its `OnPixelCombine` and setting `TBitmapLayer.DrawMode` to `dmCustom`.

Inside that `TPixelCombineEvent` method you decide what pixels result given the background `B` and the foreground `F` given the current `M` master alpha.

```
procedure TMyObj.MyPixCombine(F: TColor32; var B: TColor32; M: TColor32);
begin
  if not PseudoThisPixelShouldBeMasked then B := F; // ugly and aliased
end;
```

Problem here is, that (the pseudo code) PseudoThisPixelShouldBeMasked doesn't really know what pixel this concerns and whether it is inside a mask. So you'd have to extract that value from a component of `F`, such as its Alpha value.

Back then i opted for the quite fast `B := ColorMin(F,B);` where F is black or white. This layer is on top always and results in black instead of transparent masks however.
This because any rendering to the `TBitmapLayer` would destroy the mask data and i need to reapply it. Using a `TByteMap` however as suggested below (who downvoted that?) by iamjoosy might be interesting, perhaps that performance penalty turns out negligible.